# How to know if a user is logged in to Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

I have a Play site that's part of a larger site that uses PHP.
I would like to have the other site to behave different for users who logged in in Play (e.g., display a "logout" link instead of "login").

What is the correct way to determine, in a 3rd party server app, whether a user is logged in to Play or not? Should I just check for the existence of the `PLAY_SESSION` cookie?

I see that logging in creates this cookie, and logging out clears it, so it seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by logged in.

If you mean visiting the site (accessing the Play server) then that's the cookie you want. That cookie is created when you access the server and stores your session id amongst other data.

If you mean "using a username and password (or another authentication system) to access content on the site" then no. For that you'll probably be storing a user id in the session, which in turn will be a field in the Play cookie, and that field is what you would need to check for.

Comment: So I should parse the cookie and extract the user field? My session cookie contains this string (I truncated it for copy-paste): `%00username%3Amyemailaddress%40gmail.com` - would you suggest just looking for `%00username%3A` inside this cookie would be the way to go?

Comment: You just need an ID in the session cookie telling "this user is logged for the time being". Pere explained it quite well ;)

Comment: @ripper234 yes, check for "username" and if it is in there you know it was authenticated. If you want the user id, retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is to test the existence of `session["username"]`, with Groovy code like `#if {session.username}`in a template.

Comment: I'm not running inside play, so I don't have direct access to session variable.

Comment: @ripper234 in any case this solution is not standard, the id could be stored using any name the dev wants